# onOffsetChanged doesn't fire on HTC Sensation

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I'm developing live wallpaper on Android and recently bought a HTC Sensation (android 2.3.3) for development. The problem that I found with this phone is that `onOffsetChanged` event is not generated at all. I logged calls inside `onOffsetChanged` method and there is nothing logged on phone, while it works correctly on emulator.

My guess is that HTC Sense 3.0 messed something up (wallpapers downloaded from market doesn't work either) but on the other hand there is HTC Stream live wallpaper delivered with the phone and it seems to have such functionality.

Does anyone know if there is something special that has to be added to manifest or code that enables this functionality on HTC Sensation? Did anyone faced same problem? I'm quite confused since even google doesn't seem to know about such issue :).

Thanks for your help.